Partial SVD of sparse matrix up to cut-off relative to maximum singular value
I'm looking for a more efficient way to truncate the singular value decomposition of a large sparse array. I know that there exists method and I have an idea in mind, but I was wondering if there is an already existing solution to my problem.
I have rather large sparse array A, currently of shape (7218, 2121), but I would like to increase its size which is why I want to make the code more efficient. About 98% of the entries are zeros, so it absolutely makes sense to use a sparse matrix representation.
From this array I compute the SVD via scipy.linalg.svd, define a relative threshold at which the singular values are cut off as it is done in scipy.linalg.pinv, and use it to compute the pseudo-inverse of the large sparse matrix. Since the function pinv does exactly that, there is no benefit in switching to it. At first, I thought it would be more efficient in that sense that the truncation is done already during the computation of the SVD. But after looking into the code, I realized it just uses the full SVD and truncates it afterwards.
I know, that partial SVDs exist such as scipy.sparse.svds but instead of providing a relative cut-off threshold, one can only specify the absolute number of singular values to be computed. There is a tolerance parameter tol, but the number of returned SVs would still be limited by the parameter k.
Is there an elegant solution to this problem, already implemented, potentially also in other python packages? I'm not bound to scipy. If not, my approach would be as follows, and I would like to know, if it makes sense:

Compute the partial SVD for the k largest singular values.
Sort them in descending order (as svds does not guarantee the order, according to the docs)
Compare the smallest SV to the largest. If the cut-off threshold is reached, stops. Otherwise:

Compute the difference matrix M = A - U Σ V_h
Compute the partial SVD of M for the k largest singular values
Sort the SVs of M (and the orthonormal vectors accordingly) and append them to the partial SVD of A
Compare the smallest and largest SVs of the concatenated set of SVs. Continue iteration, if threshold is not reached. Otherwise, stop iteration.



It's not a thorough pseudo-code yet, but I think the iteration is clear. I think I remember from my numerics lecture that most SVD algorithms actually work like that or similar under the hood anyways, or a I wrong? Is my approach wrong? Did I miss something?
I know that there exist also other partial SVD methods in other packages, e.g. sparsesvd, but they have a similar limitation. PyTorch's torch.svd_lowrank sounds a bit like what I was thinking of, since a matrix M can be passed to the function which is substracted from the main matrix before the decomposition. But it's not clear to me, why it must be randomized, and what niter does.
I also checked similar stack overflow entries, but they don't explicitely address the relative threshold I would like to use. For instance, in Singular values sorted in descending order using svds from scipy.sparse.linalg the sorting is addressed, for which I would clearly use np.argsort() to then apply the same sorting to the columns of U and the rows of V_h. The entry sparse matrix svd in python is clearly outdated, as there was no scipy SVD implementation/wrapper yet.
For completeness, this is what the sparsity pattern of the matrix looks like: (using matplotlib's spy )


Biggest question in my mind is whether U Σ V_h is sparse. If not, it may invalidate gains from terminating the svd search sooner.
